# Any idiomatic meaning of "still a bit fan"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is there any idiomatic meaning of "still a bit fan"?

The [whole quote](https://twitter.com/pivot_data/status/448128542849925120) (a user tweeting me about my software tool):

> Thanks to Nicolas for the support! All fixed. Reset settings did the trick. Still a bit fan of the tool!

Does it mean that she used to be a fan of my tool, but is not a fan anymore (now just a little bit)?

Other examples found:

> XYZ used to be fan of Justin bieber and still a bit fan of Jonas brothers too bad they broke up :(
>
> Great food at a slightly steep price, but regardless I'm still a bit fan of their Saturday buffet option.
>
> Not as much bokeh as I would have liked, but I am still a bit fan of the shot!
>
> Unlike most modellers, I'm still a bit fan on a gloss or satin finish on my models.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: He didn't know that when he asked the question. He was asking if "bit fan" had a meaning he wasn't familiar with.

Comment: Could you check your sources? The usual expression is "a bit of a fan" (in which "still" has a usual meaning of "continue to be").

Comment: @nxx Yes, that possibility has actually been addressed, and I agree. "Bit" can not be completely dismissed as what the author intended. But without the "of a" a typo seems to be more likely, especially in light of the context of the tweet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: The original quote that inspired the question was a tweet which was discussed in comments. "Thanks for the support! All fixed. Reset settings did the trick. Still a bit fan of the tool!" I suspect that "bit" is a typo. She really meant to say "big fan" which would be totally naturally sounding English.

As to the *original* (pre-edit) question concerning a possible usage of "bit fan":

I had a huge crush on Shaun Cassidy as a kid. I have to admit, I'm still a bit of a fan. "Still a bit *of a* fan" would work in all of the lines you use in your example. "Bit fan" is not an usage I've ever heard.

"Still a bit of a fan" says that you still like *whatever*, but not with the huge, tremendous zeal that you used to have.

"Bit fan" without the "of a" is most likely a typo for "big fan".

Comment: I think you nailed it. In light of OP's parallel examples, are we looking at a typo or #$#^&%$ smartphone auto-correct? :)

Comment: I hate those. They are so wrong so often :)

Comment: Why have you left the first part of the answer in at all? I was just about to downvote it as completely off the mark. I had to scroll down to get at the relevant tickbox, and I find more text effectively saying *"That's all wrong!"*. It's just an obviously Off Topic typo (the **T** and **G** keys are next to each other).

Comment: The original question didn't include the tweet at all. It was only while discussing it in chat that we saw the typo. The original question only concerned "bit fan" and its possible meaning.